# GoogleSheets JavaScript Manipulation of Conditional Formats

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a Google Form that drops responses into a shared Google Sheet. Because we need to make changes to the data on the back end but want to keep the original information intact, I copy these responses using script over to another sheet which has conditional formatting.

My problem is that the conditional formatting does not expand to include the new rows.  I know how to apply the formatting in the script itself, but these formats are based on both factors people may enter in the sheet as well as the passage of time. Conditional Formatting would be the easier/cleaner way of handling these changes, but I am prepared to manually do it using OnEdit.
However, I see in the code prompt the .setConditionalFormatRules(), but can find no documentation on it.

I have checked for this information in other questions here or in general on Google, but either no one has had this problem or their questions remain unanswered. **Is there a way to set or modify existing conditional formats using script?**

Comment: It would be helpful to show what the sheet has and what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update: on 11th April 2018, documentation for these functions became available

[Conditional Format Rule](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule)
[CFR Builder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder)
[2018-04-11 release notes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/#april_11_2018)

Additional documentation can be found in the [Sheets REST API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/conditional-formatting). What you can observe here is generally the format and structure needed to create or modify the conditional format. Syntax and parameters should be essentially equivalent, but you can verify with the official Apps Script documentation too.

For example, to apply a rule which sets the text to be white if the cell value is zero, in cell A1:

```
function disappear(sheet) {
  var rb = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule();
  var ranges = [sheet.getRange("A1")];
  rb.setFontColor("white").whenNumberEqualTo(0).setRanges(ranges);
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.push(rb.build());
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}
```